# Linking to own answer in comment of another answer

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette

If you improve on the answer of one person as a separate answer ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41593629/1180926)), is it considered OK to add a comment to the original answer telling people to look at your answer?

Comment: It is *unacceptable* that your answer did not include a link to Freddy's answer.

Comment: If your answer is that similar, I would just leave a comment on the other answer describing how you feel it can be improved.  If such a comment would be too long then maybe the differences merit another answer.

Comment: @CodyGray is it _unacceptable_ that you called Franky Freddy? ;)

Comment: @CodyGray fair enough (though I see many people make this mistake).

Comment: Hah. Whoops. Darn 5 minute rule. Anyway, if you see other people making this mistake, please edit a link into their answers.

Comment: How can you do that without changing the intent of the original author? If there is a legitimate reason to link to your own answer in someone else's, I don't think this is it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it would be totally acceptable to add a *comment* to the original answer. You can pretty much leave any comment you like, as long as it is relevant to the post and doesn't contain any personal attacks. A comment pointing to an alternative solution, or even one pointing out a flaw with the answer, is a *good* comment.

Such a comment should contain a *brief* description of your proposed modification, accompanied by a link to your answer that contains all the important details.

Speaking of which, if you're going to "riff" off of another person's answer, you need to make sure that you do two things:

1. **Give credit where credit is due**: include both the name of the person who originally provided the answer ([make sure to get it right!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342767/linking-to-own-answer-in-comment-of-another-answer#comment441095_342767)) *and* include a link to the answer itself. This is required by [the license here](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)—you are free to remix and reuse all content contributed by other users, but you must provide [*attribution*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) to the original author.
2. **Explain the *advantage* of your alternative.** It isn't useful to make a trivial change to the original code and post that version as an answer. Your alternative should actually have a notable advantage over the other version, and you should call that out explicitly at the top. Is yours faster? Less error-prone? Maybe you think it is clearer. Whatever the reason is, this helps people make the best decision about which answer they should choose, depending on their situation and concerns.

If you're asking whether it would be appropriate to *edit* their answer to include a link to yours, well, probably not. This is ultimately a judgment call, and although I can imagine certain cases where it would be appropriate, many will disagree with me (some users think edits should *only* be used for presentational issues, but I think that's overly restrictive). If you *do* decide to do this, *tread very lightly*, taking into consideration how you would be affecting that person's answer and what appears to be their recommendation. They would be well within their rights to roll back your edit if they disagreed.

Also note that if you simply leave a comment, the user might decide to edit a link to your answer into theirs. I probably would, if you actually provided something of value.